# Django unable to find css file in STATICFILES_DIR

Tags: python, django

My base.html cannot find base.css. I configured my settings.py file to point to where the css file resides but still get 404.

I have the following at bottom of settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

File system tree:

```
.
├── blog
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── blog_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── static
│   └── css
│       └── base.css
└── templates
    ├── base.html
    └── home.html
```

Thank you.

Comment: what is the value of `DEBUG` in your settings.py?

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. It worked when correcting the spelling from STATICFILES_DIR to STATICFILES_DIRS (plural).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing STATIC_ROOT.

> STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

Answer (score 1):

try this

in **settings.py**

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/static/'
```

in **urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

hope it helps